# Creating MySQL tables question, why some people create two tables that relate to each other instead of one?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm very confused in creating Tables in MySQL because I read some PHP tutorials and the authors create two tables in their database and then linking them up later in PHP using joins.

Here's an example I got from an article..

Here the author  created the table users and groups.

```
    CREATE TABLE users (
       id int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       pass varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB;

   CREATE TABLE groups (
       uid int(8) NOT NULL default '0',
       grp varchar(255) NOT NULL default ''
   ) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

When I look at it, isn't the groups table not necessary? I mean I can just create the table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
       id int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       pass varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       grp varchar(255) NOT NULL default ''
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

In this way, I can just query the database and I don't need to join the two tables together at all.

So what's the purpose of creating two tables and not one? Please explain to me why linking together two tables is better than one.

Comment: Think...think..search on the net for normalization..you should be able to find your answer yourself.

Comment: If you only create a single table, then each user is limited to a single group (or you have to jump through hoops to have a user assigned to multiple groups).

Comment: Real world scenarios are far more complicated than this, sometimes you get away with not creating additional tables but not always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I a lot of authentication systems 1 user can have multiple groups. Therefore 2 tables are necessary. If you want to have a good idea how to design your tables than you can have a read on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

even beter would be if you create a table for groups, a table for users, and a table for users in groups. This is because it's common to have multiple users in a group and users can have multiple groups (many to many relation). Many to many relations in relational databases are not possible. Therefor you need the extra table.
An other advantage of this system is that if you decide to change the group name than you don't need to change that name for each user. You can just change the name once and it's changed for all users.

You get something like this.

```
- table user
  - id
  - username
  - password
  - etc

- table groups
  - id
  - name
  - etc

- table usergroups
  - userid
  - groupid
```

You can also have a look at FCO-IM which is a more complicated method to design databases compared to ERM, but might be handy for bigger and more complicated databases.

Answer (score 3):

the keyword is '[normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)'

you have only one table. and because your lazy or tired you decide after a week to type 'mod' instead of 'moderator'... not good

if you use two (or three) tables you only have to select / type in an ID, and you can easily apply one users to multiple groups

```
CREATE TABLE users (
       user_id int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       pass varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
    ) TYPE=InnoDB;

   CREATE TABLE groups (
       group_id int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
       PRIMARY KEY (group_id)
   ) TYPE=InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE user_groups (
  user_id INT(8) NOT NULL ,
  group_id INT(8) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id) ,
  INDEX user_id (user_id ASC) ,
  INDEX group_id (group_id ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id ) REFERENCES users (user_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT group_id FOREIGN KEY (group_id ) REFERENCES groups (group_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example  (where there's only one table) you can only have a one to one relationship between a user and a group. (i.e.: A given user can only belong to one group at most.)

However, if you separate the users and groups you can easily have a much more extensive set of relationships (one to one, one to many, etc.) such as allowing a single user to belong to multiple groups, etc. whilst still being able to trivially lookup group membership for a given group. That said, you will need a third "user to group membership" table which would contain an entry for each group a given user is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird way to do it. Usually, you want a users table that has the users information (avatar, information, etc) and a groupId that is a reference to a group that exists within a groups table. Using this concept allows you to have a groups table where each group has its own information such as avatar, description, and/or groupowner. It basically reduces duplication and allows you to extend relationships.